# Why we send the same index.html file back to client using res.sendFile?

Tags: node.js, express

In the following example, the index.html contains the Form which has **action='http://127.0.0.1:8000/process_get'** and **method='GET'**.

Once the Submit button is pressed, the values of **input='text**' are sent to Http server. But why there is need to send the **index.html** file back to client? The documentation of **res.sendFile** says that it transfers the file at the given path. It doesnt say Why?

The Server has already received the input values to do the processing.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format
   response = {
      first_name:req.query.first_name,
      last_name:req.query.last_name
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Comment: There are definitely some confusing things in this example. For example, `res.end()` takes no arguments; I can only imagine the author of this example meant `res.send(JSON.stringify(response))` instead. And you mention that the form sends its GET request to port 8000, but the server is listening on port 8081, so the server will never receive that request. You are right that a server wouldn't usually send the data it received back to the client as its response, but I could at least explain that as a developer's sanity check. The rest I can't.

Comment: I realised something, If the res.sendfile code is omitted (as it does not make any sense to send the file back to client) still the form processing works as expected.